# How to get RecycleView item to re-render after making change (resetting text in textview)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am dynamically adjusting Text in TextView that is within a RecycleView item's RelativeLayout.  I am doing this to to resize it.  It looks like after resetting the Text the item does not get payed out for a while. I am inside the Adapter onBindToView() method so it does not seem like calling an adapter method like onDataChange() etc is a good idea. What should I do to get the item redrawn? The actual moment I am changing the item is onGlobalLayout() on the observer for the TextView. The TextView is one of several elements on in the item.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the adapter method `notifyItemChanged(int position)` and sending the position of the changed item, in `onBindViewHolder` will force the system to redraw the item.

If you don't have access to the item's position or in any case where you want to change multiple items you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemRangeChanged()`

Comment: @gitsensible please accept the answer if it worked for you